# How to select rows from two matrices and multiply them

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I am trying to loop through the rows in two matrices and multiply them but each attempt produces the first error below, which is clear, and a second error on dimension mismatch from the last two attempts. I have tried to change the format of the extracted rows to a form that is acceptable to stan but I don't know how to coerce them to the relevant format. How do I select the rows and multiply them please?

> SYNTAX ERROR, MESSAGE(S) FROM PARSER:
>   No matches for:
>     row_vector * row_vector
>
> Expression is ill formed.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 16:       for(i in 1:Ns) {
> 17: //        yh[i, n] = xnew[n]* beta[i];
> 18:         yh[i, n] = xnew[n]* beta[i, ];
>                                         ^
> 19: //        yh[i, n] = xnew[n]* row(beta, i);
> ```
>
> ---

My `rstan` code

```
library("rstan") 
txt <- 
  'data {
    int<lower=0> N;   
    int<lower=0> K;     
    int Ns;
    matrix[N, K] xnew;   
    matrix[Ns, K] beta;
  }
  parameters {
  }
  model {
  }
  generated quantities {
    matrix[Ns, N] yh;

    for(n in 1:N) {
      for(i in 1:Ns) {
//        yh[i, n] = xnew[n]* beta[i];
          yh[i, n] = xnew[n]* beta[i, ];
//        yh[i, n] = xnew[n]* row(beta, i);
//        yh[i, n] = xnew[n,]* row(beta, i);
//        yh[i, n] = to_vector(row(xnew, n))* to_matrix(row(beta, i));
//        yh[i, n] = to_vector(row(xnew, n))* row(beta, i);         
      }  
    }
  }

'
stan_model(model_code=txt)
```

For clarity this is what i am trying to do in base R

```
set.seed(1)
Ns=10; N=2; K=3
beta = matrix(rnorm(Ns*K), ncol=K)
xnew = matrix(rnorm(N*K), ncol=K)

yh=matrix(nr=Ns, nc=N)
for(n in 1:N) {
  for(i in 1:Ns) {
    p = as.numeric(xnew[n, , drop=FALSE] %*% beta[i,])
    yh[i, n] = p
  }  
}

#tcrossprod(beta, xnew)
```

EDIT:

This seems to do the trick:

```
yh[i, n] = dot_product(row(xnew, n), row(beta, i));
```

But is there a way to calculate this without looping through each row? (I can't see anything at https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/functions-reference/dot-products-and-specialized-products.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I made a song and dance over this ... but you can just use matrix multiplication: `yh = beta* xnew';` EDIT: following Bob's advice in the comment below I moved the matrix transpose to the `transformed data` block.

So the full code:

```
txt <- 
  "data {
    int<lower=0> N;   
    int<lower=0> K;     
    int Ns;
    matrix[N, K] xnew;   
    matrix[Ns, K] beta;
  }
  transformed data{
    matrix[K, N] xnew_t = xnew';
  }
  parameters {
  }
  model {
  }
  generated quantities {
    matrix[Ns, N] yh;
    yh = beta* xnew_t;
  }

"

fit <- stan(model_code=txt,  data = list(beta=beta, xnew=xnew, Ns=10, N=2, K=3 ),    
            chains = 1, seed = 1, iter=1, algorithm = "Fixed_param")

ex_samp = as.matrix(fit)
all.equal(yh, matrix(ex_samp[-length(ex_samp)], nc=2))
```

The relevant docs: https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/functions-reference/matrix-arithmetic-operators.html

Comment: It'd be faster with a variable `xnew_t` in the transformed data block for the transpose of `xnew`.  Otherwise, Stan has to allocate and then do the copy each iteration.  That's not too bad, because it's just once per iteration, not once per log density and gradient, and it uses `double` arithmetic rather than autodiff.